# How to detect which social media is requesting for an object present in s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an s3 bucket in which I am currently blocking request access via `Referrer`. I know `Referrer` can be easily manipulated to get access of the object but I am not concerned much about that for now.
But now I want some images to get access to social media platforms. ( I need them as `og:image` ).
I can't find anyway to give access to that specific images to specific platforms.

Comment: Are you asking how to serve different S3 objects depending on the referer header or simply how to require a specific referer header when serving a specific S3 object?

Answer (score 0):

The way you can implement that by using Cloudfront on top of S3, you need to enable origin identity access to prevent direct access to s3, so all links need to be accessed only through CloudFront.

then you can enable blocking based on referrer

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-prevent-hotlinking-by-using-aws-waf-amazon-cloudfront-and-referer-checking/

Also cloudfront can have aws waf firewall to have even more advanced rules

Comment: I have seen Referrer. But whatsapp and other ones they are not using their referrer as whatsapp.com/*  or *.whatsapp.com/*. They are not working

Comment: You can add firewall in front of cloudfront to handle this case

Comment: But in cloudfront also how to block them. I have never used cloudfront but I have no problem using it. But I am asking how will be able to get specific social media platforms

Comment: did you check the example link I sent you, you only need to implement an exact copy

Comment: I saw that. The thing is how to know what is the Referrer for whatsapp?

Comment: Well, you need to be clear on your question, you asked to block based on referrer, now you're asking how to block WhatsApp which does not have a referrer !!

Comment: I told above in my question I am already using Referrer.But the ones which are not providing Referrer or we don't know their Referrer , how to block them. Since they are famous platforms do we have any policies given by aws or if someones other ways to block them. That was what I was expecting from my question